# browser buttons call actions with submitting forms in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, action, browser-security

browser forward and backward buttons call actions with submitting forms in struts2

(ex.Login form).i need to submit forms **just manually clicking the submit button** of the form.

following code can be used to prevent calling actions by **typing url.**

```
String referrer = servletRequest.getHeader("referer");
```

but browser buttons act as clicking the submit buttons and therefore they submit forms.

any help in advance.thanks.!

Comment: that's how browser work.

Comment: but i don't need to submit forms by browser's back and forward buttons.how can i do it?

Comment: i am not sure about disabling browser button.What specific use-case you want to handle as one alternate way is to clear the browser cache by using appropriate HTTP headers

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Umesh said. You can try adding some headers in the http response which will clear cache every time you click back or forward button. This is quite effective if you add this in the interceptor.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0`enter code here`
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
```

This should resolve your problem.